# OctoberCMS getPath for multiple files

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I have a problem which I cannot seem to resolve, I am uploading multiple files on the frontend but I need to get the paths of these files so that I can download the files in another program.

My model looks like this:

```
public $attachMany = [
    'fileuploader' => 'System\Models\File'
];
```

Then I tried something silly like this on the component:

```
$quote->fileuploader = Input::file('fileuploader');

foreach ($quote->fileuploader as $file) {
            Db::table('auto_quotes')->where('quote_no', $quote->quote_no)->update(['path' => $file->fileuploader->getPath()]);
        }
```

But I get a result of getPath = null.

Anyone perhaps know how I should go about this?

Comment: is it ok that first you let that files upload and save that model, then you can update `auto_quotes` model with path ? means you can get path on disk after the files are uploaded and that related `quote` model is saved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm may be your code require little bit correction,

also we need to `save $quote` to use its `files` i guess.

```
$quote->fileuploader = Input::file('fileuploader');

// save it before using
$quote->save();

foreach ($quote->fileuploader as $file) {
    Db::table('auto_quotes')
      ->where('quote_no', $quote->quote_no)
      ->update(['path' => $file->getPath()]); // <- correction
}
```

> instead of using `$file->fileuploader->getPath()` just use `$file->getPath()`

as we are already looping through `$quote->fileuploader` and each file will be `$file` so we don't need to use `$file->fileuploader` we can use `$file` itself

if still getting issue please comment.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried it but get an error message:
`Method getPath does not exist.`

Comment: `$quote->save();` can you add this code before `loop` i added it in answer. please check it and let me know

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would save my file somewhere after upload, then it will be easy to save path **so that you can download the files in another program**:

```
public function savePath($file)
{
    $file = Input::file('fileuploader');
    $destinationPath = ‘storage/uploads/yourFolder’;                        

    $file->move($destinationPath,$file->getClientOriginalName());
    Db::table('auto_quotes')->where('quote_no', $quote->quote_no)->update(['path' => $destinationPath]);
}
```

It’s up to you if you need to save `$destinationPath` or                 `$destinationPath.$file->getClientOriginalName()`

PS: Store your files in `storage` folder, if not you may have permission issue